# HTML div Comment box with arrow & image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a comment box with an arrow. I am using the CSS, but I have a problem that I cannot solve.
When I place the Image the comment box is going down the image. The comment box doesn't point to the image.
Cannot Add the comment box left of image. comment box pointing to image.

Here is the code

```
.left {
  width: 920px !important;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  min-height: auto !important;
  padding-right: 0;
  float: left;
}

.left > p:first-of-type {
  background: #ffd987;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.tip {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.tip:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -14px;
  left: 98px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 14px solid #fff;
  border-left: 14px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
}
.tip:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 99px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #fff;
  border-left: 12px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
.tip.left:before {
  border-top: 14px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: -28px;
  top: 20px;
}
.tip.left:after {
  border-top: 12px solid transparent;
  border-right: 12px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
  left: -24px;
  top: 22px;
}
```

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt=" hgell" hspace="20">

<div style="padding:50px">
  <div class="tip left">


   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam consectetur quam a sapien egestas eget scelerisque lectus tempor. Duis placerat tellus at erat pellentesque nec ultricies erat molestie. Integer nec orci id tortor molestie porta. Suspendisse eu sagittis quam.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam consectetur quam a sapien egestas eget scelerisque lectus tempor. Duis placerat tellus at erat pellentesque nec ultricies erat molestie. Integer nec orci id tortor molestie porta. Suspendisse eu sagittis quam.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try a float left?

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply the "float" style to the image:

```
img{
    float:left;
}
```

(**important!** : if you have multiple images get them an own class/id)
remove this padding

```
<div style="padding:50px">
```

and be aware that on screens with a width under 920px, it will still be shown as before (`width: 920px !important;`)

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fp3rwkoh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to float the image at the left.

**Note** I've changed the image just for try this spinnet.

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  }
.left {
    width: 920px !important;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    min-height: auto !important;
    padding-right: 0;
    float: left;
}

.left > p:first-of-type {
    background: #ffd987;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.tip {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

.tip:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -14px;
    left: 98px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 14px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 14px solid #fff;
    border-left: 14px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    content: '';
}

.tip:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    left: 99px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid #fff;
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    content: '';
}

.tip.left:before {
    border-top: 14px solid transparent;
    border-right: 14px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    left: -28px;
    top: 20px;
}

.tip.left:after {
    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    left: -24px;
    top: 22px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://uk.rs-online.com/catimages/F0108038-01.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt=" hgell" hspace="20">

<div style="padding:50px">
<div class="tip left">


   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam consectetur quam a sapien egestas eget scelerisque lectus tempor. Duis placerat tellus at erat pellentesque nec ultricies erat molestie. Integer nec orci id tortor molestie porta. Suspendisse eu sagittis quam.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam consectetur quam a sapien egestas eget scelerisque lectus tempor. Duis placerat tellus at erat pellentesque nec ultricies erat molestie. Integer nec orci id tortor molestie porta. Suspendisse eu sagittis quam.
</div>
</div>
```